# How to add different textures in same .obj through object id in sceneform?

Tags: java, android, arcore, sceneform

I have a .obj model in server which is loaded into ModelRenderable using Uri.parse(""). All i can do is load single texture in whole model by uv mapping.
But i want to load a model with multiple texture from id o Mesh01 and o Mesh02 are the object name inside the model.
My code for model render is:

```
ModelRenderable.builder()
          .setSource(this, RenderableSource.builder().setSource(
                  this,Uri.parse(url2),RenderableSource.SourceType.GLB)
                  .setScale(0.1f)  // Scale the original model to 50%.
                  .setRecenterMode(RenderableSource.RecenterMode.CENTER)
                  .build())
           //.setSource(this, R.raw.model)
          //.setRegistryId(GLTF_ASSET)
          .build()
           .thenAcceptBoth(futureTexture, (renderable, texture) -> {
               andyRenderable = renderable;
               Log.d("rikesh", "onCreate: "+andyRenderable.getSubmeshCount());
               andyRenderable.getMaterial().setTexture("baseColor", texture);
           })
          .exceptionally(
                  throwable -> {
                      Toast toast =
                              Toast.makeText(this, "Unable to load renderable " +
                                      url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                      toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                      toast.show();
                      return null;
                  });
```

and the code for .obj model are
[o Mesh01 and o Mesh02 are the objects of the .obj model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPsA9.png)
where i want to put textures inside it.